# "error: no associated program", CBR files can't be opened

Tags: windows, calibre

I get `Error: No associated program` error message when trying to open [CBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_archive) (comic book archive) files. Calibre (3.23) has been associated with this file format in Windows and the error appears whether opening from the library or Windows file explorer.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must enable Calibre's internal viewer for the format.

Go to "preferences":

[image: screenshot]

"behavior":

[image: screenshot]

enable CBR and CBZ (one of comic book archive's filename extensions) formats and apply changes:

[image: screenshot]

[source](https://www.howtogeek.com/291916/how-to-view-cbr-and-cbz-comic-books-in-calibre/)

Comment: Strange, that helped, thank you.